# Java URLConnection header name

Tags: java, url, header

I am using this piece of code to later download a file from an URL.

```
            URL url = new URL("http://smarthome-de.censored.net/Installer.zip");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            int size = conn.getContentLength();
            String type = conn.getContentType();
```

Is there a way to catch the files name from an URL?
That I can store "Installer.zip" to a String without getting this value because of its known.

I found out getContentType() gives me type. Sadly I don't find any method for the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the file name from the `Content-Disposition` header:

```
String contentDisposition = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
```

Please note that this header is set by the server and is not guaranteed to be present. HTTP clients that download files use the `Content-Disposition` if it is present or default to the last part of the URL which in your example would be `Installer.zip`.

The Content-Disposition header content is something like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Installer.zip"
```

You have to parse the header value to extract the filename part.
For more details you can take a look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition